# ガワネイティブアプリのログイン状態監視方法について

Tags: swift, ios, android, 詳細設計

ガワネイティブアプリにてログイン状態を監視する良い方法はありますでしょうか？

今回の要件として、ログイン画面のみスマホネイティブで実装し、認証を終えたらログイン後のスマホ最適化されたウェブサイトを表示させます。ユーザーがウェブサイトをログアウトした場合、もしくはセッションが切れてしまった場合は、ネイティブのログイン画面を再表示させたいです。

セッションが切れてしまった場合にログイン画面を表示させる際、ネイティブ側でウェブサイトのログイン状態を把握している必要があると思うのですが、その方法はどういったものが考えられるでしょうか。

みなさまの知恵をお貸しいただけたら幸いです。

環境
iOS10.2
Android6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidでWebViewを使用しているのであればaddJavascriptInterfaceで
JavaScriptからをJava側のオブジェクトのメソッドを実行できます。
ですので、ログアウトの処理が行われる部分でJavaScript経由でネイティブに通知すればよいと思います。
なお、セキュリティのリスクがあるのでリファレンスマニュアル等を参照してください。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。調べてみたとろ、iOS・AndroidのWebViewともJsvaScriptからネイティブのメソッド実行ができるのですね。こちらの機能を利用し、実装させていただきます。大変参考になりました。